# How long can a company wait before withdrawing the money of a purchase?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, expiration

In November, 2015 I purchased something from an online shop located in the UK.

Total price was 143£ (including shipping to Denmark) and I paid with my Visa credit card.

The item was shipped to me fast, and in excellent condition, however the money was never withdrawn from my account. Now it's been almost two years ago, and the money still hasn't been withdrawn from my account.

Is there an expiration date on these kind of online purchases? Should I expect the money to be withdrawn at any time?

Comment: I would assume that they will either find it at the end of their business year (which happened to me once), or never. But I don't know for sure if they legally can do it later; probably they can.

Comment: "Now it's been almost two years ago" - That year is long gone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I paid with my Visa credit card.

Generally on credit cards, the holds / authorizations are valid for a month on single transactions. So if you haven't been charged on your card, it seems that there was some technical error with the online market place. They were not able to trace this.

> Is there an expiration date on these kind of online purchases? Should I expect the money to be withdrawn at any time?

There are 2 different aspects, one is do you still owe them money and can they ask you; It would be yes, I don't know the timelines. This would depend on establishing a contract etc. They can contact you for unpaid invoice.

Can they again charge the credit card automatically ... generally No.